# How to dynamically add daemon & to end of curl

Tags: bash, curl, daemon

On my first run I need curl to run and wait for response.  DB has a trigger that updates a field and I need to wait for that.  Then on all my other curls to run on separate threads.  I cannot use the parallel options for curl as the version we have does not have it and I cannot update it anyway so I have to go old school and do

```
for ...
  curl "some curl options" &
end for loop

wait # this waits for all the threads to finish
```

So I need the "&" sign to be set after the first run.  FYI my curl command is 20 lines long and I did try this at the end of the curl command but it doesn't work.  Trying single and double quotes around the & sign doesn't work either and give me "unexpected end of file" error.

```
$(if [[ $firstRun == false ]]; then echo & fi)
```

Comment: Why don't you just do the first one outside the loop?

Comment: The curl command is huge and has many conditionals in it.  It would be ugly code and just bad coding practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a wrapper function to conditionally run its arguments as a command in the background:

```
conditionalbg() {
    if [ "$1" = true ]; then
        shift
        # run the passed command in the foreground
        "$@" &
    else
        shift
        # run the passed command in the foreground
        "$@"
    fi
}

...
runinbg=false
for ...
    conditionalbg "$runinbg" curl "some curl options"
    runinbg=true
end for loop
```

Comment: This appears to be the best solution for my situation!  Logic is reversed but easily fixed.  When true then don't daemon it.  For all others then add the &.  Thank you for the speedy response!

Answer (score 0):

You can't add syntax to command lines dynamically. So just write two identical commands, one without `&`.

```
firstRun=true
for ...; do
    if [[ $firstRun = true ]]
    then 
        curl "some curl options" 
        firstRun=false
    else
        curl "some curl options" &
    fi
done
wait
```

If you don't want to repeat the whole `curl` command, put it in a function.

Answer (score 0):

Put your curl command in a function then call the function with or without `&` as appropriate:

```
doCurl() {
    curl "some curl options"
}

doCurl
for ...
  doCurl &
end for loop

wait # this waits for all the threads to finish
```